# Tabs breaking my slider CSS in Wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

i'm having a issue with a wordpress theme i'm working.
Further informations:

Theme name: Language School(tabs are also from him)

Slider plugin name: DHVC WooCommerce Slider(sitesao)

The problem is: i have made some tabs and in each tab i use a shortcode from the slider.

Each one of them is a category like photographic, video editor, light techniques. The first tab works fine like the picture above:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pza1.png (sorry, not enough rep to post images)

But the other ones are with a bad css config, as the image below shows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhZks.png (sorry, not enough rep to post images)²

A user called magenta helped me and said its a problem where the css needs to be overrided. These are the class's: div.owl_stage and div.owl-item, they need to have his width fixed.

After, css transform:translate3d also needs to be overidden.

I tried to make this in my wordpress css editor but it only fix the images. He said it need to be made in a javascript code(10 ~20 lines of code) but i dont know much of js. Can someone please help me?

If needed, this is the website: https://estudefotografia.com/teste and the tabs i said.

Thanks people!
sorry for any english mistake, its not my native language.

Comment: I previously worked on this question but I am now too busy to continue. Let me provide a more technical description of the problem. The tab widget is implemented by the theme language-school and the slider widget is implemented by the plugin dhvc-woocommerce. These two plugins were not designed to work together. The slider widget dynamically computes the width of the slider and slider elements and applies these widths to those elements (inline style).

Comment: I think the problem is except for the first tab when the silder widget does this calculation the tab widget has not yet set the width of the tab causing the widths of the slider and slider items to be way too small. Using the developer's console of the browser I reset these widths to more reasonable values and the page appears normal. So one possible fix is to do this using JavaScript.

Comment: Hey @magenta thanks for your help again! Hope someone can help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [magenta answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49712841/9622607), you can try this code:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.cmsmasters_tabs ul.cmsmasters_tabs_list li a')
        .on('click', function() {
            // Defines width for animation
            jQuery('div.cmsmasters_tab div.owl-stage').width('150vw');
            jQuery('div.cmsmasters_tab div.owl-item').width('20vw');

            // Delay to not be overridden
            setTimeout(function() {
                var stageElement = jQuery('div.cmsmasters_tab.active_tab div.owl-stage');
                var itemElements = jQuery('div.cmsmasters_tab.active_tab div.owl-item');
                var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
                // Width defined based on breakpoints
                var itemWidth = windowWidth > 1024?
                    313.333:
                    windowWidth <= 1024 && windowWidth>= 600?
                        windowWidth * .3:
                        windowWidth * .9;
                // Apply the changes
                itemElements.width( itemWidth + 'px' );
                stageElement.width( itemElements.length * itemWidth + 'px' );
            }, 200);
        });
});
```

The problem is that the widget code is acting after your jQuery code, the delay reverses the order. This will adjust mobile and act after the widget miscalculate the width. If the code don't work at first, try bigger values on the setTimeout function.

Comment: All working now, many thanks to you and @magenta
My problem now is solved!

Comment: There are two things that still need to be done. If you look at the initial tab you will see that exactly 3 images are displayed. You can acheive this by using the width of a suitable container in your calculation. Second, the left/right arrows scroll the slider exactly one image width. You can achieve this by overriding the left/right arrows handler.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your theme's function.php

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
?>
<script>
    jQuery( function() {
        jQuery( '.cmsmasters_tabs ul.cmsmasters_tabs_list li a' ).on( 'click', function() {
            // When the tab is changed set width of slider items and width of slider in active tab to something reasonable
            var itemWidth = 20;
            var items = jQuery( 'div.cmsmasters_tab.active_tab div.owl-item' ).width( itemWidth + 'vw' );
            jQuery( 'div.cmsmasters_tab.active_tab div.owl-stage' ).width( jQuery( 'div.cmsmasters_tab.active_tab div.owl-item' ).length * itemWidth + 'vw' );
        } );
    } );
</script>
<?php
}, 1000000 );
```

This is just the first iteration, will probably require much adjustment. (You can change the itemWidth and see what effect it has. This is set to an absolute value for now but probably needs to be set relative to the width of some parent container.) I cannot run this experiment on my installation so you will need to do this yourself. The slide increment will also need fixing but we will fix that later after we get the initial display working.

Comment: sorry for the delay in answering you, i was sick yesterday. I added the code, its working and i appreciate your help so far. 

The only problem is: i need to click twice in the tab to the changes make effect. How can i fix this?

Again, thank you so much dude!